# Best practice for many to many data mapping

Tags: sql, database

I am looking to find the best practice for many to many mapping in database.

For example I have two tables to be mapped. I create third table to store this mapping.

[image: Database Diagram]

On UI I have several A to be mapped(or not) multiple with B. And I see two solutions for now:

1 - On every update for every record from A I will delete all mapped data for it and insert new data mapping.

- Advantage: I store only mapped data.
- Disadvantage: I need to use delete and insert statement every time.

2 - I need to add new bit column to AB table with name isMapped. And I will store all mapping for every record from A to every record from B. On save mapping action I will use only update statement.

- Advantage: No need to delete and insert every time.
- Disadvantage: Need to store unnecessary records.

Can you offer me best solution?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think you have to delete all mapped data for every update in A table (1)? Mapping itself is not changed if you update ,for instance, `AName`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

between the 2 options you have listed I would go with option no 1, isMapped is not meaningful, if they are not mapped the records should not exists in the first place.

you still have one more option though:

```
DELETE FROM AB where Not in the new map
INSERT INTO AB FROM (New map) where NOT in AB
```

if these are a lot of maps I would delete and insert from the new mapping, otherwise I would just delete all then insert like you are suggesting.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say anytime you see the second bullet point in your #2 scenario

"Need to store unnecessary records"

that's your red flag not to use that scenario.

Your data is modeled correctly in scenario 1, i.e. mapppings exist in the mapping table when there are mappings between records in A and B and mappings do not exist in the mapping table when there is not a mapping between those records in A and B.

Also, the underlying mechanics of an update statement are a delete and then an insert, so you are not really saving the database any work by issuing one over the other.

Lastly, speaking of saving the database work, don't try and do it at this stage.  This is what they are designed for. :)

Implementing your data model correctly as you are in Scenario 1 is the best optimization you can make.

Once you have the basic normalized structure in place and have some test data, then you can start testing performance and refactoring if necessary.  Adding indexes, changing data structures, etc.